# Title: How to create a DAX formula in Power BI for Week-to-Date (WTD) comparison with previous year by week?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to build a DAX formula in Power BI that allows me to compare week-to-date (WTD) values for the current year with the corresponding week from the previous year. Specifically , I want to create a measure that calculates the difference in values between the current WTD and the same period last year on a week-by-week basis.

Could someone provide guidance on how to structure this DAX formula to achieve this Year-over-Year (YoY) comparison for WTD values in Power BI? Any insights, examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have been testing different DAX codes to achieve a Year-over-Year (YoY) comparison for week-to-date (WTD) values in Power BI. So far, I have only been successful in calculating Year-to-Date (YTD) and Quarter-to-Date (QTD) values. However, I am struggling to find a solution for WTD comparison between the current year and the previous year on a week-by-week basis.

Could someone provide guidance on how to structure a DAX formula to achieve this YoY comparison for WTD values in Power BI? Any insights, examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI doesn't have good week to date functions which is why I *love* to have offsets in my date table. Do you have a date table? If so, do you have any columns about weeks?

Here's what I would do. Either create offsets in your date table or use this example m code for a [new](https://github.com/dataDad/PowerBI/blob/main/Date%20Table%20with%20Offsets) date table. (learn more about offsets [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r09wlvwMh50))

```
 let
    // configurations start
    Today=Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), // today's date
    FromYear = 2020, // set the start year of the date dimension. dates start from 1st of January of this year
    ToYear=2025, // set the end year of the date dimension. dates end at 31st of December of this year
    StartofFiscalYear=7, // set the month number that is start of the financial year. example; if fiscal year start is July, value is 7
    firstDayofWeek=Day.Monday, // set the week's start day, values: Day.Monday, Day.Sunday....
    // configuration end
    FromDate=#date(FromYear,1,1),
    ToDate=#date(ToYear,12,31),
    Source=List.Dates(
        FromDate,
        Duration.Days(ToDate-FromDate)+1,
        #duration(1,0,0,0)
    ),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "Date"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Year", each Date.Year([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Start of Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Year", "Start of Year", each Date.StartOfYear([Date]), type date),
    #"Inserted End of Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Start of Year", "End of Year", each Date.EndOfYear([Date]), type date),
    #"Inserted Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted End of Year", "Month", each Date.Month([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Start of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month", "Start of Month", each Date.StartOfMonth([Date]), type date),
    #"Inserted End of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Start of Month", "End of Month", each Date.EndOfMonth([Date]), type date),
    #"Inserted Days in Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted End of Month", "Days in Month", each Date.DaysInMonth([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Day" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Days in Month", "Day", each Date.Day([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Day Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day", "Day Name", each Date.DayOfWeekName([Date]), type text),
    #"Inserted Day of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day Name", "Day of Week", each Date.DayOfWeek([Date],firstDayofWeek), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Day of Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day of Week", "Day of Year", each Date.DayOfYear([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Month Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day of Year", "Month Name", each Date.MonthName([Date]), type text),
    #"Inserted Quarter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month Name", "Quarter", each Date.QuarterOfYear([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Start of Quarter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Quarter", "Start of Quarter", each Date.StartOfQuarter([Date]), type date),
    #"Inserted End of Quarter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Start of Quarter", "End of Quarter", each Date.EndOfQuarter([Date]), type date),
    #"Inserted Week of Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted End of Quarter", "Week of Year", each Date.WeekOfYear([Date],firstDayofWeek), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Week of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Week of Year", "Week of Month", each Date.WeekOfMonth([Date],firstDayofWeek), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Start of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Week of Month", "Start of Week", each Date.StartOfWeek([Date],firstDayofWeek), type date),
    #"Inserted End of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Start of Week", "End of Week", each Date.EndOfWeek([Date],firstDayofWeek), type date),
    FiscalMonthBaseIndex=13-StartofFiscalYear,
    adjustedFiscalMonthBaseIndex=if(FiscalMonthBaseIndex>=12 or FiscalMonthBaseIndex<0) then 0 else FiscalMonthBaseIndex,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted End of Week", "FiscalBaseDate", each Date.AddMonths([Date],adjustedFiscalMonthBaseIndex)),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"FiscalBaseDate", type date}}),
    #"Inserted Year1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Year.1", each Date.Year([FiscalBaseDate]), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Year1",{{"Year.1", "Fiscal Year"}}),
    #"Inserted Quarter1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Quarter.1", each Date.QuarterOfYear([FiscalBaseDate]), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Quarter1",{{"Quarter.1", "Fiscal Quarter"}}),
    #"Inserted Month1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns2", "Month.1", each Date.Month([FiscalBaseDate]), Int64.Type),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Month1",{{"Month.1", "Fiscal Month"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns3",{"FiscalBaseDate"}),
    #"Inserted Age" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Age", each [Date]-Today, type duration),
    #"Extracted Days" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Age",{{"Age", Duration.Days, Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Extracted Days",{{"Age", "Day Offset"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns4", "Month Offset", each (([Year]-Date.Year(Today))*12)
+([Month]-Date.Month(Today))),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"Month Offset", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Year Offset", each [Year]-Date.Year(Today)),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom2",{{"Year Offset", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type3", "Quarter Offset", each (([Year]-Date.Year(Today))*4)
+([Quarter]-Date.QuarterOfYear(Today))),

    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom3",{{"Quarter Offset", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type4", "Year-Month", each Date.ToText([Date],"MMM yyyy")),
      #"Add Week Offset" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Week Offset", each ( Number.From( Date.StartOfWeek( [Date], Day.Sunday) )- Number.From( Date.StartOfWeek( Today, Day.Sunday ) ) ) / 7, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Week Offset", "Year-Month Code", each Date.ToText([Date],"yyyyMM")),
    #"Changed Type5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom5",{{"Year-Month", type text}, {"Year-Month Code", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type5"
```

After you have your week offset column, create new measures like

Last Week Sum = CALCULATE(SUM([your value here]),Date[Week Offset] = 0)

Prior Year Last Week Sumh= CALCULATE(SUM([your value here]),Date[Week Offset] = -53)

You could then find the difference between the two measures for your variance. This might seem like a lot if you don't have a date table, but it is really a best practice to have a date table you can use in all of your reporting.

It's common to publish this table in dataflows so it can be easily consumed with any report.